# Is it important to have integers inserted using %d rather than %s?

Tags: database, wpdb

Is it important to have integers inserted using `%d` rather than `%s`?

I have a situation where there is a large number of fields and values.  When database changes are made, it is difficult to match all the field types to the data format.  It would be much easier to have them all be `%s`, even integers, but I am not sure of the ramifications of that.

```
    $data = array(
            
        'field1'    => $this->val1,
        'field2'    => $this->val2,
        'field3'    => $this->val3,
<snip>
        'field100'  => $this->val4
     )

$format = array(  '%d', '%s', '%d',  <snip> '%s');

$wpdb->insert( $db_example, $data, $format );
```

I know the `format` option is optional, again, what are the possible ramifications of not using it at all?

Answer (score 2):

Going by the description for the `$format` argument

> An array of formats to be mapped to each of the value in $data. If string, that format will be used for all of the values in $data. A format is one of '%d', '%f', '%s' (integer, float, string). If omitted, all values in $data will be treated as strings unless otherwise specified in wpdb::$field_types.

So unless the type is important for your column structure you can leave it as string.

You can however create a dynamic format array if you want to, something like this.

```php
$data = [
    'This is a string', // string
    55, // integer
    3.7, // float (double)
    true, // boolean
];

$format = array_map(function ($value) {
    switch (gettype($value)) {
        case 'string':
            return '%s';
        case 'integer':
            return '%d';
        case 'double':
            return '%f';
        default:
            return '%s';
    }
}, $data);

print_r($format);
```

You can test this on https://3v4l.org/

What we have here is a basic format builder based on the type of each array element, we always default to `%s`, also there is no need for a `break;` as we always `return`.

You can create a function out of this if you see that you use this multiple times, that was you can keep your code DRY.